# Template method pattern with setTimeout in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, template-method-pattern

I have a `close` function that will close some instance. The class that includes the function allows derived classes to override `close`. Here, I want to make sure that `close` always calls `dispose` even in derived classes. I achieve this by the following.

```
function close() {
  closeCore();
  dispose();
}

function closeCore() {
  // derived class can override this method.
}
```

This works fine, but I have one case where I want to perform CSS animation before I dispose the instance. This is what I do.

```
function close () {
  instance.classList.add("fancy-animation-that-takes-800ms");

  setTimeout(function () {
    dispose();
  },800);
}
```

But as soon as I do this, the template pattern I use cannot be applied. Is there a way to make sure the close function always call dispose in the second example?

Comment: Parameterize `close` function (with an optional param `disposalTimeout` passed meaning `dispose` should be called async).

Comment: @raina77ow, can you maybe show an example by posting it as an answer? Btw, I want to do it without adding a new parameter to the function.

Comment: `function close(disposeTimeout /* = false */) { /* ... */ if(disposeTimeout) { setTimeout(dispose, disposeTimeout) } else { dispose(); }`

Comment: Thank you, that works, but I am still looking for a way without adding a new parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have `close` expect an object be returned from `closeCore` which had parameters like these:

```
return {timeout: 800, callback: function () {/*....will execute after a timeout..*/}};
```

or:

```
return {callback: function () { /*...will be immediately executed...*/}};
```

or:

```
return function () { /*...will be immediately executed...*/};
```

...and then call their timeout for them (if any), and then after your timeout executed their callback, then call `dispose` for them.

The relevant part of your `close` code might look like:

```
function close() {
  var ccObj = closeCore();
  var ccIsObj = ccObj && typeof ccObj === 'object';
  var callback = typeof ccObj === 'function' ? ccObj : (ccIsObj ? ccObj.callback : null);
  if (ccIsObj && ccObj.timeout) {
    if (!callback) {
      throw 'You must implement a callback when supplying a timeout';
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        callback();
        dispose();
    }, ccObj.timeout);
  }
  else {
    if (callback) {callback();}
    dispose();
  }
}
```

But if you want to allow the user to make arbitrary asynchronous calls of their own (such as Ajax), while you could instead allow the returning of a promise to which you added the `dispose` call, you wouldn't have a guarantee that the deriver would ensure the promise completed. You could automatically cancel the promise after a certain period of time, but you couldn't magically know when the deriving code was meant to finish unless again you abstracted this.